# PowerBI Report Iframe does not responds to html-css in ipad

Tags: css, ipad, iframe

I am trying to embed an iframe in a division through HTML-CSS. The styling is working fine on the desktop i.e. report will resize based on its container and scrolling appears for the report. The same code is not working on iPad Safari browser. Can anyone suggest what will be the possible issue?

Comment: We cannot suggest anything until you specify what _exactly_ is not working as there are a lot of CSS rules that do not work in specific environment. I recently faced an issue with `min-height: calc(...)` not working under certain conditions on iOS. Might a similar situation be your case? When revising your styles you can check compatibility at [caniuse.com](caniuse.com).

Comment: @lolbas I am using the GreenSock library. [link](https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/dPZLEp) Hit the URL and in JS section replace last line code "my message" to "<iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" src=\"https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiNmJjNGY4YWMtODBmOS00YWNlLTg1MzgtMDE4YjYwODdmMjcwIiwidCI6ImYyZDQ5ZTFmLWE2MWQtNDBkMC1hYWY1LTI5Mzc0MGY1NTAxMyIsImMiOjZ9\" frameborder=\"0\" allowFullScreen=\"true\"></iframe>".

There in the 1st division report will be displayed in the Output window. This seems fine on desktop but on ipad report overflows the div container